# IIS 7.5 delete binding

Tags: iis-7.5

I am looking for a way to delete range of Host header binding from my IIS, 
any idea? There is have some batch script that will know to delete chunk of binding settings?

Answer (score 0):

There is powershell command to remove them Remove-WebBindings - see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790591.aspx

This could be used with Get-WebBindings and a filter to do what you want